# in mysql, does quantity of data in one table affect performance

Tags: mysql, performance

Setting up a new database that has a comments table. I've been told to expect this table to get extremely large. I'm wondering if there is any particular reason why I wouldn't want to keep this table in the same database as the rest of the data for the site.

Comment: This is somewhat tangential (hence a comment, not an answer) but in my experience it can help performance to put the meta-data for bulky tables, into a separate table. So you might have 'comments_meta' with PK, author_id, post_id, maybe some thread-related columns if relevant, etc... and then a separate 'comments' table with just two columns: PK (linking back to 'comments_meta') and 'comment_data'. Then in situations where you just need meta-data, your queries won't have to touch the bigger table. YMMV

Comment: @Ben Dunlap: That's going to depend entirely on which engine is being used.  Innodb, for instance, already stores TEXT and BLOB columns separately from the other columns, this it wouldn't make an impact there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quantity of data will certainly affect performance in any RDBMS, however, there's no reason that this table should exist in a separate database on the same server.  If the table truly will become very large with a lot of insert activity, then you might want to consider an [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) process that keeps an [indexed](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) copy for fast selection (mostly because indexes can negatively affect inserts despite the performance gain on selects)

Comment: +1 for the link to ETL. Now I have an official TLA for what I would have called, before today, my "gnarly performance hack".

Answer (score 1):

Keep the table in the same database for now, but it is well known that insert speed slows as the number of records increases.

There are some options to consider if the performance becomes unacceptable, for instance, if the data can be partitioned, split it across multiple tables in separate databases.